# how to create virtual host for rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualhost, crowdsourcing

I have two rails application. one is [crowd sourcing platform from github](http://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter.)

I put this on my server. now it runs on my local server. I have another domain. And want to put this crowd sourcing platform in my domain. How to do that and how to make virtual host for that?

Thanks , Zeel

Answer (score -1):

You could try deploying it to heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

Comment: Thank you for responce but Can you please explain some more because i am new in rails programming. @Mark Stratmann

Comment: ok first a few questions. 1.  Is your project set up in a Git source control repository.  2.  do you have DNS control over your domain, that is can you add CNAME entires to your domain?  3.  Have you looked at the instructions in the link in my answer?

Comment: This did not solve the problem of making a local Virtual Host other than http://localhost:3000/.